# How to loop and render elements in React.js without an array of objects to map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to convert a jQuery component to React.js and one of the things I'm having difficulty with is rendering n number of elements based on a for loop.

I understand this is not possible, or recommended and that where an array exists in the model it makes complete sense to use `map`.  That's fine, but what about when you do not have an array?  Instead you have numeric value which equates to a given number of elements to render, then what should you do?

Here's my example, I want to prefix a element with an arbitrary number of span tags based on it's hierarchical level.  So at level 3, I want 3 span tags before the text element.

In javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < level; i++) {
    $el.append('<span class="indent"></span>');
}
$el.append('Some text value');
```

I can't seem to get this, or anything similar to work in a JSX React.js component.  Instead I had to do the following, first building a temp array to the correct length and then looping the array.

React.js

```
render: function() {
  var tmp = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.props.level; i++) {
    tmp.push(i);
  }
  var indents = tmp.map(function (i) {
    return (
      <span className='indent'></span>
    );
  });

  return (
    ...
    {indents}
    "Some text value"
    ...
  );
}
```

Surely this can't be the best, or only way to achieve this?   What am I missing?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children.map

Comment: also you could just do that: https://jsfiddle.net/crl/69z2wepo/19804/

Answer (score 282, accepted):

**Updated: As of React > 0.16**

Render method does not necessarily have to return a single element. An array can also be returned.

```
var indents = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.props.level; i++) {
  indents.push(<span className='indent' key={i}></span>);
}
return indents;
```

OR

```
return this.props.level.map((item, index) => (
    <span className="indent" key={index}>
        {index}
    </span>
));
```

[**Docs here explaining about JSX children**](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#jsx-children)

---

**OLD:**

You can use one loop instead

```
var indents = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.props.level; i++) {
  indents.push(<span className='indent' key={i}></span>);
}
return (
   <div>
    {indents}
    "Some text value"
   </div>
);
```

You can also use [**.map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and fancy es6

```
return (
   <div>
    {this.props.level.map((item, index) => (
       <span className='indent' key={index} />
    ))}
    "Some text value"
   </div>
);
```

Also, you have to wrap the return value in a container. I used div in the above example

As the docs say [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/maximum-number-of-jsx-root-nodes.html)

> Currently, in a component's render, you can only return one node; if you have, say, a list of divs to return, you must wrap your components within a div, span or any other component.

Comment: That works, and it's much simpler thanks.  Yes I'm aware that you have to wrap return value in container, I'm doing that already it's just missing from the example.

Comment: add keys inside the loop. keys are important in react.

Comment: in the loop, need to use `key={i}`, *not* `key=i`, because the latter throws `JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text`.

Comment: i've been looking for you all of my life

Comment: so it is important to wrap the element in return ? Is there any alternative without wrapping up we can return multiple elements

Comment: What if I want to only render the {indents}, without the enclosing div?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen Its not possible. It has to be wrapped with some tag. If {indents} returns a single dom elements with content inside it, then its ok

Comment: If you are using any linting, you may get a warning to not use your index as the key. The warning comes appears for either iterative approach. You could abstract the key's reference outside of your function:  


```let myKey = 0;

array.map((item, index) => {
  myKey += 1;
  return (
    <span className='indent' key={myKey} />
  );
});``` . 


This is pretty simplistic. For a more complex app, you may want to ensure the key is unique. You could prepend or append an additional identifier to make it so.

Comment: I don't understand why the map method is mentioned in this answer, as it does only work for Array objects, which the question clearly states is not the case.

Answer (score 50):

Here is more functional example with some ES6 features:

```
'use strict';

const React = require('react');

function renderArticles(articles) {
    if (articles.length > 0) {      
        return articles.map((article, index) => (
            <Article key={index} article={article} />
        ));
    }
    else return [];
}

const Article = ({article}) => {
    return ( 
        <article key={article.id}>
            <a href={article.link}>{article.title}</a>
            <p>{article.description}</p>
        </article>
    );
};

const Articles = React.createClass({
    render() {
        const articles = renderArticles(this.props.articles);

        return (
            <section>
                { articles }
            </section>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Articles;
```

Comment: This looks like the most 'Reacty' way to do it. Pass values as props to another sub component. Thanks!

Comment: This is a great! Perfect for when your render() is html heavy.

Comment: To make it more ES6 you could use `import React from "react"` and `export default Articles`

Comment: This answer doesn't even attempt to answer the question. The question was clear, how to convert a `for loop` to a map'able array (or object) in order to render n number of items in a React component without having an array of items.  You solution completely ignores that fact and assumes being passed an array of articles from props.

Comment: The question is very specific about NOT having an array of objects.

Answer (score 36):

[`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) takes an iterable object to convert to an array and an optional map function. You could create an object with a `.length` property as follows:

```
return Array.from({length: this.props.level}, (item, index) => 
  <span className="indent" key={index}></span>
);
```

Comment: Just what I needed for rendering X number of elements, thank you!

Answer (score 16):

I'm using `Object.keys(chars).map(...)` to loop in render

```
// chars = {a:true, b:false, ..., z:false}

render() {
    return (
       <div>
        {chars && Object.keys(chars).map(function(char, idx) {
            return <span key={idx}>{char}</span>;
        }.bind(this))}
        "Some text value"
       </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Your answer worked for me, but only after I added `chars && ...` and `.bind(this)` on the end of my function. I'm curious why merely `Object...`(so on and so forth) didn't work. I kept getting undefined.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it specifically says without an array of objects to parse and the explanation explicitly says that I want to convert a for loop to map for rendering in a React component. You substituted array for an object which doesn't help answer the question, or add any further value.

Answer (score 7):

You can still use `map` if you can *afford* to create a makeshift array:

```
{
    new Array(this.props.level).fill(0).map((_, index) => (
        <span className='indent' key={index}></span>
    ))
}
```

This works because `new Array(n).fill(x)` creates an array of size `n` filled with `x`, which can then aid `map`.

[image: array-fill]

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the easiest way to loop in react js

```
<ul>
    {yourarray.map((item)=><li>{item}</li>)}
</ul>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, please read the question in full before attempting to answer.