# How to use the reactJS to append DOM elements with loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

How to use the reactJS to append DOM elements with loop. 
 
I use the way Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149169/how-to-loop-and-render-elements-in-react-js-without-an-array-of-objects-to-map/29149361)
 
After compiler these code still get the error with :

> Uncaught Error: Content.render(): A valid React element (or null)
>   must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some
>   other invalid object.

```
        var Content = React.createClass({
            render: function () {
                var dom_content = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    dom_content.push(<li className='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 block'><div className='box'></div></li>);
                }
                return dom_content;
            }
        });
        ReactDOM.render(
                <Content />,
                document.getElementById('the_box')
                );
```

Comment: change `return dom_content;` to `return {dom_content};`

Comment: Which version of React ?

Comment: You are using a VEERY old React Version. Thats not how you do that nowadays. Id recommend you to use the latest react version.

Comment: Okay I will try the latest react version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dom_content` is an array.

You need [React 16](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#new-render-return-types-fragments-and-strings) to directly render it.

> You can now return an array of elements from a component’s render method. Like with other arrays, you’ll need to add a key to each element to avoid the key warning

If you don't want to/cannot use React 16, wrap it in a div.

```
render: function () {
    var dom_content = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        dom_content.push(
            (
                <li 
                    key={i} // Add this too =)
                    className='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 block'
                >
                    <div className='box'></div>
                </li>
            )
        );
    }
    return (
        <div> // or <ul> ??
            {dom_content}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing them to an array object called dom_content. As the error message suggests, you can return only react elements from render method. In this case you're returning a javascript object.
Try something like:

```
new Array(3).map(() => (<li className='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 block'><div className='box'></div></li>));
```