# What should I do to successfully map data from axios API?

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios, mapping

How do I map out the data I've put in my console/state? I've been trying to add a map function where I left the "//m", and it seems like it should be simple enough but I can't seem to do it properly.

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"; 
 import axios from "axios"; 
 import EmployeeDetail from "./EmployeeDetail";

 function App() {
    const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
                       setLoading(true);
                       axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10&nat=us")
                            .then(res => { 
                                            console.log(res.data.results);
                                            setEmployees(...res.data.results);
                                            setLoading(false);
                                         })
                            .catch(err => {
                                            console.log(err);
                                          });
                    }, []); 
        
return ( 
  <div className="App"> 
  <h1>Employee List</h1>  
  //m
  </div>
);
}
export default App;
```

I was able to make it using the API the guy in the youtube video I referenced used ("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all") with the following function:

```
   {countries.map((country) => (
<div key={country.name}> 
{country.name} - {country-capital}
</div> 
))}
```

I'm just having problems with doing it with my own API.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems you are looking for rendering a table of output data from an API call.

When you call `setEmployees()`, react application will refresh the page using virtual DOM as you are setting a state using react hooks mechanism.

```
return(){
   <div className="App"> 
      <h1>Employee List</h1>  
         <table>
           <thead>
              // your table headers
           </thead>
           <tbody>
                 {this.employees.map((item, index) => {
                                                       <tr>
                                                          <td>{item.value1}</td>
                                                          <td>{item.value2}</td>
                                                          // as per your requirement
                                                       </tr>  
                                                      })}
           </tbody>
         </table>       
  </div>
}
```

One more thing you can do is, create a function and return JSX from function.

Please visit below link for creating function and returning JSX.

[How to loop and render elements in React.js without an array of objects to map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149169/how-to-loop-and-render-elements-in-react-js-without-an-array-of-objects-to-map)

Answer (score 0):

You can use map as you want.

```
return ( 
  <div className="App"> 
    <h1>Employee List</h1>  
    <ul>
      {
        emplyees.map((employee) =>
          <li>{employee.name}</li>
        );
      }
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

There is a detailed document that you could follow step by step [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)